# PHP - Preventing Line breaks in Dynamically Created Text area

Tags: php, arrays, regex, csv, line-breaks

I have a form with sets of inputs that can be dynamically created -- [see here](http://codepen.io/theodore_steiner/pen/YGrNbB).

In order to push the values gathered from these inputs to a `.csv` sheet and keep them together in a single cell, I am using the following PHP function. It gathers the content from the 3 inputs, saves it to the `.csv` in a single cell, and for every new iteration of inputs, it just separates the entries with a "//" but keeps it in the same cell (like this: President, 2015, I was the president// Vice President, 2014, I was the vice president).

**PHP**

```
$provincialInvolvement = $_POST["provincialInvolvement"];
$provincialInvolvementValues = "";
$e = 0;

foreach($provincialInvolvement as $piValue)
    {
        $provincialInvolvementValues .= $piValue;
        $e++;
        if($e % 3 == 0)
            {
                $provincialInvolvementValues .= "//";
            }

    }
```

My problem is because the last input is a textarea, if a line break is put in (someone hits the enter key) it breaks the form of the `.csv` and puts it on a new line.

I am trying to write a function onto the portion of my PHP that, as it logs the value into `$provincialInvolvementValues` it removes any linebreaks but I;m having no luck.

Here is the function problem is it doesn't log anything.

```
$provincialInvolvement = $_POST["provincialInvolvement"];
$provincialInvolvementValues = "";
$e = 0;

foreach($provincialInvolvement as $piValue)
    {
        $provincialInvolvementValues .= $piValue;
        $e++;
        $provincialInvolvementValues = preg_replace( "/(\r|\n)/ ", "", $provincialInvolvementValues ); 
        return $provincialInvolvementValues;
        if($e % 3 == 0)
            {
                $provincialInvolvementValues .= "//";
            }

    }
```

Comment: Maybe try this: `preg_replace( "\r?\n\s*", "", $provincialInvolvementValues)` - newlines are usually `\n` or `\r\n` so this might work better. Also, the `return $provincialInvolvementValues;` is probably wrong in the loop...

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you sir!

Comment: Glad it worked, I've added it as answer so you can accept it the problem is solved by that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try this: `preg_replace( "\r?\n\s*", "", $provincialInvolvementValues)` - newlines are usually `\n` or `\r\n` so this might work better.

Also, the `return $provincialInvolvementValues;` is probably wrong in the loop...